# Errors Connecting to Postgres from PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm having issues connecting to a postgres database in PHP.

This is always failing:

```
$db = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=MYDB user=MYUSER password=MYPASS") or die("Connection failed");
```

Although this works fine from the command line:

```
psql -U MYUSER -d MYDB --password -h localhost
```

pgsql shows up in phpinfo()

Any ideas what the issue might be?

Comment: Perhaps try this? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-connect.php#74277

Answer (score 0):

Thanks cillosis, you were very close (and that solution may also work). I resolved it by adding a port number, possibly necessary because Postgres 8.4 operates on port 5433 by default rather than 5432.

This works fine:

```
$db = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5433 dbname=MYDB user=MYUSER password=MYPASS")
```